# Favicon issue in browsers

Tags: html, asp.net, css, favicon

I have a favicon with

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

Its in root of project. My problem is when i ran it first time, it gave icon in project correctly but when i ran it again as i was checking for changes in IE compatibility, it could not find icon. It ran before in FF and Chrome, but had some issue in IE. i tried using

```
<link rel="Shortcut Icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

but didnt work.

Comment: Have you tried using `href="/favicon.ico"` or `href="http://www.yoursite.com/favicon.ico"`

Comment: You may need to reset your browser(s) cache. It would also be more useful to provide more code or a link to the project, if available (as there may be an underlying issue with your code as a whole).

Comment: <link rel="icon" href="http://www.example.com/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.example.com/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code it works for me in IE as well.

```
<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="favicon.ico" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Your can create favicon image using this [link](http://www.favicon.co.uk/index.php)
You can place your image in your website.

Then you can put this

`<link rel="Shortcut Icon" href="http://www.baseurl.com/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />`

```
http://www.baseurl.com/ (or) http://www.yourwebsite.com/
```

This baseurl should be given in your LINK tag

That's all

Answer (score 1):

This will work, use this,

```
<link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
```